# Only one of all my divs is draggable

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Here is the problem : I have to make my p tags whith the class ".draggable" draggable. 
I have this code :

```
<div id="dragArea">
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="list" id="traitement">Traitement vidéo</div>
            <p class="items draggable traitement" id="transcoder">Transcoder la vidéo</p>
            <p class="items draggable traitement" id="addLogo">Ajouter un logo</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tab">
            <div class="list" id="publication">Publication</div>
            <p class="items draggable publication" id="genLecteur">Générer un lecteur vidéo</p>
            <hr class="items publication"/>
            <p class="items draggable publication" id="facebook">Publier sur Facebook</p>
            <p class="items draggable publication" id="twitter">Publier sur Twitter</p>
            <p class="items draggable publication" id="dailymotion">Publier sur DailyMotion</p>
            <p class="items draggable publication" id="youtube">Publier sur Youtube</p>
            <p class="items draggable publication" id="vimeo">Publier sur Vimeo</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tab">
            <div class="list" id="divers">Divers</div>
            <p class="items draggable divers" id="mail">Envoyer une notification par mail</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And to make these tags draggable :

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
                helper : 'clone',
                cursor : "move",
                revert : true,
                containment : ".bloc.page"
            });
```

But when I watch my page, there is only the last ".draggable" item (id="mail") which is draggable.
I tried to put a red background color by the same way and it works, so I don't find my error.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: seems fine at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bRkfA/

Comment: I checked @Arun fiddle, and it didn't work for me until I removed the attributes ie `$(".draggable").draggable();` then it worked for me. On debian 6 chrome 19.